# Как передать значение переменной из JS в <form action>?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть тестовая страница. Суть её в следующем: она генерирует длинную URL (3144000 символа) и при нажатии кнопки редиректит на сгенерированную линку. На данный момент страница имеет такой вид:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>longLink</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="position.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script language="javascript">

         function Go(Val1, Val2) {
            var obj = document.myform
            obj.val1.value = Val1
            obj.val2.value = Val2
            obj.submit()
         }

         function randomLink(len) {
            var protocol = "http://";
            var extension = ".html";
            var linkBody = '';
            while (linkBody.length < len) linkBody += Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, len - linkBody.length);
            return protocol + linkBody + extension;
         }

         var generatedLink = randomLink(3144000);
         document.getElementById("mytext").value = generatedLink;
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <button onclick="Go(1, 2)">REDIRECTION</button>
      <form name="myform" action="mytext">
         <input type="hidden" name="val1">
         <input type="hidden" name="val2">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Если не использовать функцию randomLink(), а просто захардкодить линку в 3+ млн символов в form action="http://test.html", то редирект отрабатывает как надо. Но я хочу обойтись без хардкода, а генерировать линку на лету и передавать её в form action="http://test.html". Я с JS не работаю, а тут вот понадобилось. Генератор строки нагуглил, так что нет полной уверенности, что он работает правильно.

Вот мой пример, который полностью отрабатывает как надо, но с хардкодом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>longLink</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="position.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script language="javascript">

         function Go(Val1, Val2) {
            var obj = document.myform
            obj.val1.value = Val1
            obj.val2.value = Val2
            obj.submit()
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <button onclick="Go(1, 2)">REDIRECTION</button>
      <form name="myform" action="http://3mlnsSymbols.html">
         <input type="hidden" name="val1">
         <input type="hidden" name="val2">
      </form>
   </body>
</html
```

Может кто подсказать, либо как правильно генерировать линку в виде стринги и передавать её в form action, либо хотя бы указать, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За атрибут `action` отвечает [одноименное свойство](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/action), поэтому достаточно установить ему нужное значение:

```
var obj = document.myform;
obj.action = generatedLink;
```